# Null space and dimension of a function $\langle x,a\rangle a$

Tags: linear-algebra

Can anyone tell me if/where I am going wrong if I argue as below to answer the following question?

Let $A$ be an $n$-dimensional linear space ($n \in \mathbb N$), and let $L : A \to A$ be given by
$$L(x) = \langle x,a\rangle a$$

where $a$ is a given vector in $A$.
(a) Find the null space of $L$, and the dimension of the null space.
(b) Let $b$ belong to $A$. Under what condition does the equation
$L(x) = b$
has solutions? Find the solutions.

So here is my approach:

The inner product of $\langle x,a\rangle$ yields a scalar.
This is multiplied to a fixed vector '$a$' specified/prescribed beforehand.
Thus $L$ is a scaling operator.

1. This means it cannot change the dimension of '$a$', only its magnitude. Therefore its dimension is the same as that of $A$, i.e. '$n$'.
2. Since the null space is the solutions that leave the vector '$a$' unchanged it implies, the null space is all vectors $c$ that belong in $A$, such that $\langle c,a\rangle = 1$, as this leaves '$a$' unchanged after the operator works on them
3. Condition for $b$ to have valid solutions is that $b$ belongs in the null space, i.e, all $\langle b,a\rangle =1\Rightarrow b = 1/(||b||\cdot||a||\cdot\cos(\theta))$

Thank you so much for helping me learn!
-Kat

Comment: In the problem statement, you define $L(x) = a$, but in the title, you refer to the function $\langle x,a\rangle a$, which is not mentioned in the problem statement. Did you mean to define $L(x) = \langle x,a\rangle a$?

Comment: It's wrong what you write about thte null space. The null space of $L$ is the set of all vectors that $L$ maps to the zero vector.

Comment: Bungo: My bad! L(x) = <x,a>a

Comment: Friedrich, I thought the null space of L is all those x belonging to A that leave the vector 'a' unchanged? I was confused about whether it is that it must actually take a to zero? In that case, a vector 'c' such that <c,a>a =0 is the solution space. Which would mean all c perpendicular to a. Yes? Thank you for setting that straight

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Friedrich Philipp in the comments, the null space of $L$ is the set of $x \in A$ such that $L(x) = 0$. In this problem, $L(x) = \langle x,a \rangle a$. There are two cases to consider.

**Case 1:** $a \neq 0$.

In this case, $\langle x,a \rangle a = 0$ if and only if $\langle x,a \rangle = 0$ if and only if $x$ is orthogonal to $a$ if and only if $x$ is orthogonal to every vector in the subspace spanned by $a$. Since the latter subspace has dimension $1$, the dimension of the null space is $n-1$.

**Case 2:** $a = 0$.

In this case, $\langle x,a \rangle a = 0$ for all $x \in A$, so the null space is all of $A$, hence its dimension is $n$.

---

Now let $b \in A$ and consider the equation $L(x) = b$. A solution exists if and only if $b$ is in the image of $L$, if and only if there exists $x \in A$ such that $L(x) = \langle x,a\rangle a = b$. If a solution exists, say $x_0$, then $x_0 + y$ is also a solution for any $y \in \text{null}(L)$, and in fact this characterizes all of the solutions.

To find a solution when one exists, we again consider two cases.

**Case 1:** $a \neq 0$.

In this case, the equation $\langle x,a\rangle a = b$ requires that $b$ must be a scalar multiple of $a$, in other words a solution exists only if $b = \lambda a$ for some scalar $\lambda$. Assuming this is true, we can substitute $b = \lambda a$ into the equation to obtain $\langle x,a\rangle a = \lambda a$. One solution to this is $x_0 = (\lambda / \langle a,a\rangle)a$, as can be verified by plugging it in and simplifying. The full set of solutions is then $\{x_0 + y : y \in \text{null}(L)\}$, often written more compactly as $x_0 + \text{null}(L)$.

**Case 2:** $a = 0$.

In this case, $L(x) = 0$, so the equation becomes $0 = b$. This has a solution if and only if $b = 0$, in which case every $x \in A$ is a solution.